# Adicionar +1d na data atual php

Tags: php, data

Tenho a seguinte data:

```
$data = date("Y-d-m H:i:s");
```

Preciso criar a seguinte data:

```
$data_expira = date("Y-d-m H:i:s"); // adicionando +24h
```

Como eu posso adicionar +1d na data atual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**resultado ideone**](https://ideone.com/Dl0AUv)

A partir do PHP 5.2.0, há uma maneira simples de se trabalhar com datas e horários, com a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.construct.php) - retorna um novo objeto DateTime

```
$date = new DateTime('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Outra forma: [**resultado ideone**](https://ideone.com/638OX4)

```
 $amanha = date("Y-d-m H:i:s", time() + 86400);
 echo $amanha;
```

Outra forma: [**resultado ideone**](https://ideone.com/ESpKdx)

```
$amanha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 days'));
echo $amanha;
```

Para horario local use [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)   — configura o fuso horário padrão utilizado por todas as funções de data e hora em um script

[**Exemplo ideone**](https://ideone.com/8DCU2y) com  `date_default_timezone_set ("America/Sao_Paulo");`